# Target collapseable accordion content from link

Tags: javascript, html

I have a working page with a collapseable accordion. It does what I need it to do, you click on the link and it drops down the content (see link below).

What I'm curious to know, how can I make it so that if I click on a link from a different page that lands on the below page, how can I make that link drop to a certain group which then expands the content automatically without clicking the group? Something I need to add to the JS.. Then separately I would need something for the link that is targeting the content that would make it drop down.

This is all of the content that works: https://codepen.io/bootpen/pen/BooWaR

Again I just need an example of how a link would look and what JS I would have to add.

Thanks!

```js
/*******************************
* ACCORDION WITH TOGGLE ICONS
*******************************/
 function toggleIcon(e) {
        $(e.target)
            .prev('.panel-heading')
            .find(".more-less")
            .toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
    }
    $('.panel-group').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
    $('.panel-group').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say you have a link or button that triggers this.

Button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="goToTwo()">Click to go to #2</button>
```

You'll want to add a unique ID to the Anchor tag  of each group `id="group-2"` for example

Click Handler:

```
function goToTwo() {
    var num2 = '#group-2';

    document.querySelector(num2).scrollIntoView();

    $(num2).trigger('click');
}
```

working CodePen: https://codepen.io/lucksp/pen/aLrGRp

Comment: This works awesome! However, How would I make this work using a link? I try this, but it doesn't work:

<a href="PATH OF LINK" onclick="goToTwo()">Click to go to #2</a>

Comment: do you mean a link on a completely separate URL address that is not on the same page?

Comment: Correct. That's exactly what I need.

Comment: Would I need to add some JS to the page in which this link would be on as well?

Comment: I figured this out and got it working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great! I was just going to post you need a `<a href="otherpage.html#elementID">Jump</a>` and `window.location.hash` as the location in the click handler